# C - cant use integer, to char* works. add 1 not. Something is wrong

Tags: c

This might be a noob question but i am working to figure this out for 2 days now and cant get it to work;
I am adding debug logs everyware and unable to solve this one.
What happens here?
( sorry for probably a noob question )

This part is killing me;

```
#define MAX_LINE_LEN 1000

int hlsconfdata;
hlsconfdata=0;

f = fopen("/data/.hlsconf", "r");
if (!f)
{
    ALOGI("Error opening config file ");
}
else
{
    char line[MAX_LINE_LEN];
    while (fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LEN, f))
    {
        hlsconfdata = (int)line;
        ALOGI("Got HLS config set to: (%s)", (char*)hlsconfdata);
    }
    if (!feof(f))
    {
        ALOGI("Error reading HLS config file ");       
    }
}
fclose(f);  

int count;
count = hlsconfdata + 1;

ALOGI("Processing Config for configuration: (%s)", (char*)hlsconfdata);
ALOGI(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>add 1: (%s)", (char*)count);

if (hlsconfdata == 0)
{
    ALOGI(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> got 0");
}
else if (hlsconfdata == 1)
{
    ALOGI(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> got 1");
}
else if (hlsconfdata == 2)
{
    ALOGI(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> got 2");
}
else if (hlsconfdata == 3)
{
    ALOGI(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> got 3");
}
else 
{
    ALOGI(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> got NOTHING");
}
```

The log output:

```
Got config set to: (2) Processing Config for configuration: (2)
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>add 1: ()
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> got NOTHING
```

So `hlsconfdata` has a value when converting to char.
when adding 1 or compare it as an integer it has no value (or something else)
Can someone shed a light on this.

Please note this is added the android AOSP source, if that is important to know.

Comment: All your casts are completely wrong. Please search for "C++ convert int to string" (or the reverse).

Comment: You cannot cast arbitrary integer values to char*.  If you want to display it, do printf("%d\n", hlsconfdata).

Comment: What does `ALOGI` do? If it's just a direct interface to a `printf`-tyle function, then the pointer casts are impossibly wrong. Also, this has very little to do with C++, it's pure C code.

Comment: noted.. changed topic to C.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth It's not an arbitrary integer value, though, it's an integer value that was obtained from a pointer (to a local whose lifetime has ended). The code looks fragile, but I don't think `%d` is what's meant.

Comment: ALOGI is the output on the android logcat

Comment: @hvd: good point. So there are actually two problems!

Comment: I realy banged my head over this.. anyone have an idea how to get a proper integer and get it to validate in the if statement as that is all i want to accomplish. the log output i just added to see what happens.

Comment: `hlsconfdata = (int)line;` can potentially corrupt/truncate the pointer (you should remove the `(int)` cast), the `!feof` test means you're insisting on a one-line file, so the `while()` loop is pointless, `int count; `count = hlsconfdata + 1;` is again assuming `int` is big enough to store your `char*` - it's not guaranteed.  And ultimately the problem you've obviously noticed is that `hlsconfdata` is a pointer to the buffer containing the line, and not the ASCII value of a character in the line.  Try `hlfsconfdata[1]` to "see" the '1' printed earlier.

Comment: Tip: use `#include <fstream> ... if (std::ifstream file(filename)) { int n; if (file >> n) ...use n here...; }` to open a file and read a number from it....

Comment: Ok will give it a go.. still figuring this C out..  you mean using hlfsconfdata[1] in the if statement?

Comment: the code is implemented here: [link](http://git.gnorth.ru/andr442_rbox_sdk.git/blob/master/frameworks/av/media/libmediaplayerservice/MediaPlayerFactory.cpp) inserted at line 242 just above "#if NUPLAYER_ENABLE_URL_CHECK". this might shed some light to someone.

Comment: `hlsconfdata = (int)line;` will set the variable `hlsconfdata` to hold the memory address of your character buffer.  `hlsconfdata` will have nothing to do with any of the characters that were read. The conditions `if (hlsconfdata == 1)` etc. will always be false, because your buffer is not at that address. Is that what you intended?

Comment: can you explain why you want to read all of the lines into the same buffer (each line overwriting the previous line) ?

Comment: yes the goal is to read the file line to an integer (number) and then make it compare it in an if statement so we can alter the outcome of the script

Comment: like hlsconfdata should hold a number from 0 to 3 and we can do a .. 'if (hlsconfdata == 1)'  or 'if (hlsconfdata == 2)'

Comment: @Martin make sure you understand the difference between a sequence of characters that holds a text representation of an integer, and an actual integer. Some programming languages are fairly loose with the concept but C isn't  ; there's a world of difference between `123` and `"123"` .

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments, it seems that the file should contain a text representation of an integer, and you want to convert this to an integer.

If so, then change this:

```
hlsconfdata = (int)line;
ALOGI("Got HLS config set to: (%s)", (char*)hlsconfdata);
```

to this:

```
hlsconfdata = atoi(line);
ALOGI("Got HLS config set to: (%d)", line);
```

and also change this:

```
ALOGI("Processing Config for configuration: (%s)", (char*)hlsconfdata);
ALOGI(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>add 1: (%s)", (char*)count);
```

to this:

```
ALOGI("Processing Config for configuration: (%d)", hlsconfdata);
ALOGI(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>add 1: (%d)", count);
```

Using casts is a sign that you are probably doing something wrong.  The effect of `(int)line` is to convert *the memory address* of `line` to an integer. It does not read the characters that are stored in `line`.

Your original code appears to partially work because you store the address of `line` in the int, then retrieve it again by converting back to `char *`, and so the `%s` specifier looks up the contents of `line`.   But you run into trouble when you do `+1` on the int in between as then you no longer retrieve the original buffer (in fact you would probably retrieve a pointer to the second character of the buffer, resulting in the line being displayed without its first character).

---

Another problem is that your `while` loop reads the whole file but it overwrites each line with the next line, so you display a whole lot of `"Got HLS config set to:"` (assuming the file has more than 1 line) but you only actually use the last line of the file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very sure I understood your problem correctly, but to me, it looks like, the problem is in the below code.

```
    hlsconfdata = (int)line;
    ALOGI("Got HLS config set to: (%s)", (char*)hlsconfdata);
```

**Point 1.** You cannot convert a `char[]` (string) to `int` by using a cast. You've to use [`strtol()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol).

Use

```
long int hlsconfdata;
```

and

```
hlsconfdata = strtol(line, NULL, 0); //just for example.
```

**Point 2.** You cannot cast an `int` to `char *` to print as a *string*. Maybe what you want is

```
ALOGI("Got HLS config set to: (%s)", line);   //print as string
```

or

```
ALOGI("Got HLS config set to: (%ld)", hlsconfdata);   //print as integer
```

Comment: when i do this the result is allways NULL. i have to go now, will check in later today again. the code is implemented here: [link](http://git.gnorth.ru/andr442_rbox_sdk.git/blob/master/frameworks/av/media/libmediaplayerservice/MediaPlayerFactory.cpp) inserted at line 242 just above "#if NUPLAYER_ENABLE_URL_CHECK". this might shed some light to someone.

Comment: the goal is to switch the used android player. the java part in android is working just fine and puts the file in place with a single character "0", "1", "2" or "3". i have to read this character to (in this case a integer) or any thing else and make a if statement to know what to do.. i realy dont get it anymore.. 10 hours passed again :(.. this is what i want to do: 1. read one line of a file to an integer value. 2 make an if statement to set the task to do. if 1 then.. if 2 then.. thanks for all you help guys

Answer (score -2):

count=hlsconfdata + 1;this code is wrong ,you can't access char line[MAX_LINE_LEN],becasue it's life is end after { } .

Comment: the problem i face is that ALOGI("Processing Config for configuration: (%s)", (char*)hlsconfdata); gives me the output i need but i can not seem to verify it with if (hlsconfdata == 1).. is hlsconfdata not an integer as in "number" ?